# Show tooltip text in a string with custom tags

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I have a string with custom tags and try to get the text for the *tooltip* and add it in the `<span>` propery *title*. I replaced the custom `[message]` tag with `<span>` but how to get the *text* property by *code*. I tried some options with `match` and `includes` but maybe I'm wrong. If anyone can help me I will be very grateful. Тhanks.

```
let obj = [
  {
    code: 'MESSAGE_1',
    text: 'Basic tooltip text',
    type: 'TOOLTIP'
  },
  {
    code: 'MESSAGE_2',
    text: 'Again, basic tooltip text',
    type: 'TOOLTIP'
  },
];

let str = 'A really ironic artisan [message type="TOOLTIP" code="MESSAGE_1"]whatever keytar[/message], scenester farm-to-table banksy Austin twitter handle freegan cred raw denim [message type="TOOLTIP" code="MESSAGE_2"]single-origin[/message] coffee viral.'

let updateStr = str.replace(/(\[message[^\]]*\])(.+?)(\[\/message\])/g, '<span class="tooltip" title="">$2</span>');
```

Expected output:

```
A really ironic artisan <span class="tooltip" title="Basic tooltip text">whatever keytar</span>, scenester farm-to-table banksy Austin twitter handle freegan cred raw denim <span class="tooltip" title="Again, basic tooltip text">single-origin</span> coffee viral.
```

Comment: Yes, this is the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
let obj = [
  {
    code: 'MESSAGE_1',
    text: 'Basic tooltip text',
    type: 'TOOLTIP'
  },
  {
    code: 'MESSAGE_2',
    text: 'Again, basic tooltip text',
    type: 'TOOLTIP'
  },
];

let str = 'A really ironic artisan [message type="TOOLTIP" code="MESSAGE_1"]whatever keytar[/message], scenester farm-to-table banksy Austin twitter handle freegan cred raw denim [message type="TOOLTIP" code="MESSAGE_2"]single-origin[/message] coffee viral.'

let updateStr = str.replace(/\[message[^\]]*\scode="([^"]*)"[^\]]*]([\w\W]*?)\[\/message]/g, (_,code,text) => `<span class="tooltip" title="${obj.find(x=> x.code == code).text}">${text}</span>`);
console.log(updateStr);
```

The `\[message[^\]]*\scode="([^"]*)"[^\]]*]([\w\W]*?)\[\/message]` regex matches

- `\[message` - `[message` text
- `[^\]]*` - zero or more chars other than `]`
- `\scode="` - a single whitespace and `code="` text
- `([^"]*)` - Group 1 (`code` in replacement): any zero or more chars other than `"`
- `"[^\]]*]` - `"`, any zero or more chars other than `]` and then a `]` char
- `([\w\W]*?)` - Group 2 (`text` variable in replacement): any zero or more chars as few as possible
- `\[\/message]` - a `[/message]` string.